# How to specify a location with the rewrite tactic?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a simple lemma for lists which says `n::l = [n]++l` whose proof appears below.

```
Lemma cons_to_app : (forall (n: nat) (l: list nat),  n :: l = [n] ++ l).
Proof.
  simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Now I want to use this proof rewrite cons terms `::` wherever they appear in the proof goal. For example, consider following.

```
Lemma easy_lemma : forall (n : nat) (xs ys : list nat), (n::xs) ++ (n::ys) = (n::xs) ++ ([n] ++ ys).
```

I would like to rewrite the `(n::ys)` to `[n] ++ ys` and the proof is done. Since `n::ys` is the second time that `::` appears in the proof goal, I thought that `rewrite const_to_app at 2` would work, but actually it acts on the 3rd `::` and changes the proof goal to `(n :: xs) ++ n :: ys = ([n] ++ xs) ++ [n] ++ ys`.

What location can I specify to make the rewrite work on the `(n::ys)` term?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that `rewrite lemma at n` instantiates the equality using the first occurrence (`(n::xs)` in this case) and *then* rewrites its nth occurrence (2nd of `(n::xs)` happens to be the *3rd* `_ :: _`). So there's no `rewrite cons_to_app at n` that will rewrite `(n::ys)`. You need at least `rewrite (cons_to_app _ ys)`.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I'm looking at the tactics documentation and the entry for `rewrite at` refers to `pattern at` which says "Only the occurrences num+ of term are considered for β-expansion. Occurrences are located from left to right." Do you remember where you read what you said?

https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.pattern

Comment: @Mark Bubbler's explanation is correct, but I don't remember either where I have seen this written.

Comment: @Mark This is the best I have found: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2564#issuecomment-337507113.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still can't find the original source that talks about the exact behavior of `rewrite at` (other than [the one eponier mentioned](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/2564#issuecomment-337507113)). The post at the link was written in 2011 but seems to be still valid as of 2019 with Coq version 8.9.1, and likely won't be "fixed" because the issue was closed as "invalid" saying "changing the behavior will break backwards compatibility".

---

#### The problem

`rewrite lemma at n` instantiates the equality using the first occurrence, and then rewrites its nth occurrence.

Given the lemma to prove

```
Lemma easy_lemma :
  forall (n : nat) (xs ys : list nat), (n::xs) ++ (n::ys) = (n::xs) ++ ([n] ++ ys).
```

and the lemma used to rewrite

```
Lemma cons_to_app : (forall (n: nat) (l: list nat),  n :: l = [n] ++ l).
```

`rewrite cons_to_app at n.` always chooses the subterm `n :: xs`, then rewrites the nth occurrence of `n :: xs` to `[n] ++ xs`. The second `n :: xs` just happens to be the third `_ :: _`.

#### The solution

Simple solution is to give enough arguments to tell Coq the exact thing to rewrite. `rewrite (cons_to_app _ ys)` is enough in this case.

One alternative is to use the `setoid_rewrite` tactic, which looks at all applicable subterms. However, it sometimes looks too deep into the definitions, and indeed it's the case for this example; `setoid_rewrite cons_to_app at 1.` gives

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
xs, ys : list nat
______________________________________(1/1)
[n] ++
(fix app (l m : list nat) {struct l} : list nat := match l with
                                                   | [] => m
                                                   | a :: l1 => a :: app l1 m
                                                   end) xs (n :: ys) = (n :: xs) ++ [n] ++ ys
```

Folding the `app` gives `[n] ++ (xs ++ n :: ys)`, which is different from what we want i.e. `([n] ++ xs) ++ n :: ys`. We can observe that `setoid_rewrite` unfolded `app` once, changing the LHS to `n :: (xs ++ n :: ys)`, then instantiated the lemma to rewrite the outermost `_ :: _`.

To avoid unfolding `app`, we can declare `Opaque app.` before rewriting. Then `setoid_rewrite ... at 1` gives what we want (and so does `at 2`). To revert the effect of `Opaque`, use `Transparent`.